# Tkinter fix size of Frame to not overlap Canvas border with scrollbar

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, scrollbar, frame

I'm working on a GUI with tkinter and i have a problem.
When i add a scrollbar to my app, the frame on my canvas overlaps the outlines (see image)

[image: Screenshot of my app]

**Here is the code:**

```
from tkinter import * 

window = Tk()
window.geometry("400x225")
scrollbar1 = Scrollbar(window, orient=VERTICAL)
canvas1 = Canvas(window, bg="#003333", yscrollcommand=scrollbar1.set)
frame1 = Frame(canvas1, bg="#003333")

scrollbar1.config(command=canvas1.yview)
scrollbar1.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
canvas1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
canvas1.create_window((0, 0), window=frame1, anchor="nw")

for x in range(20):
    string = "line " + str(x)
    label1 = Label(frame1, fg="white", bg="#003333", text=string, font=("Calibri Bold", 14))
    label1.pack(pady=5)

window.update()
canvas1.config(scrollregion=canvas1.bbox("all"))

window.mainloop()
```

I don't know if it's possible but i want the frame to fit within the canvas and keeping the outlines as well.
I hope you get my problem and can probably help me out! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`highlightthickness`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/options.htm#M-highlightthickness)

> Specifies a non-negative value indicating the width of the highlight rectangle to draw around the outside of the widget when it has the input focus.

So, this is not really the "border" that you want. It is a part of the drawing space within the canvas, when you use `window_create` to draw a window, the parent of that window is the canvas, which begins before the highlight and so the window slides over it.

A solution, as also suggested by @[martineau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355230/martineau) would be to make this `0` by specifying `highlightthickness=0` and as you suggested that you need the "border" around the whole thing, you can either create a container frame and specify the `bd` parameter, or just set the `bd` of the window `window.config(bd=2)`.

Comment: Thanks man! That ```window.config(bd=2)``` was what I needed!